# SwiftUI Image not switching to dark mode when created using UIImage

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple SwiftUI view where I create a `Image` view using a `UIImage`. The issue is that the Image created with the UIImage is not switching to the dark or light mode when the color scheme changes. It works correctly only if the entire view is reloaded. It works as expected if I use create the image directly with the image name.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Image("my-image")
                Text("Image")
            }

            VStack {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "my-image")!)
                Text("Image+uiImage")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The image itself is in a xcasset catalog

[image]

result is this (note the right image not changing when the appearance changes but only after restarting the app)

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug, you should create a Feedback and submit it to Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround here is to use Image without using the UIImage constructor

Answer (score 5):

This happens when the SwiftUI `Image` is initialized using an `UIImage` (seems to be a static initialization with no further observation of the original `UIImage`).

Workaround: The view can be informed to redraw manually, when using the `colorScheme` environment variable. Even when it seems to be unused in your later code.

This is pretty useful, if you need to consume UIImages from a shared UIKit/SwiftUI codebase.

In your example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    // This is required for the automatic re-creation of the view
    // (and thus updating the Image with the appropriate appearance
    // for the UIImage)
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme // <- view get's notified

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Image("my-image")
                Text("Image")
            }

            VStack {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "my-image")!)
                Text("Image+uiImage")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that this might lead to unneeded redrawing, so try to use SwiftUI Images first, as @Jan said.